# Joomla Membership extension

Tags: seo, components, membership, joomla-extensions

I'm working on a project where I've been asigned an E-commerce kind of website. The main thing is that the company wants to sell a Downloadable PDF file and they will upgrade this file on a weekly basis. They want the client to pay anually like $50/year.

They want a membership kind of thing. For eg. three different levels of subscription namely Gold, Silver, Free.

Gold = Everything is accessible
Silver = Video section is not accessible 
Free = Only free stuff is accesible

I will apreciate if you can provide me a link to the working demo.

They also want their website to be SEO friendly too.

Thanks,
Manpreet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUGA http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/backend-a-full-access-control/2587 extension is an extension used for creating members groups and restricting access to specific areas, however it can be tricky to implement and should be in place from the begining of the build.  There are loads of free joomla SEO tools in the extension directory.

Comment: thanks, I have another concern. I don't want to the PDF file to be downloadable but I want the file to be viewed in an online PDF viewer like google docs. Will that be possible..??